# Inserting in sql Database while maybe out of range

Tags: mysql, list, keyvaluepair, indexoutofrangeexception

I have an question. I'm trying to insert some values into an mySql database, but I have a small issue.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Chauffeurlijst.Count; i++)
        {
            db.Insert("Insert into route (Voertuigen_ID,Chauffeurs_ID,Planning_ID) VALUES(@voertuigid,@chauffeurid,@planningid", new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
        {

            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@voertuigid", Voertuigenlijst[i].ID),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@chauffeurid", Chauffeurlijst[i].ID),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@planningid", planning.ID)
        });
        }
```

I have two notable variables: A voertuigenlijst(a list of voertuig) and a chauffeurlijst (a list of chauffeur) But the problem is that it could be that Voertuigenlijst's count is smaller than the count of Chauffeurlijst. It could also be the same. When the chauffeurlijst is smaller the program will ofcourse crash because the last item in the list of voertuigen already has been allocated. What I would like to do is when the voertuigenlijst[i] doesn't exist anymore I want to do i-1. Is there a nice solution for this problem?

Comment: why not check i inside the loop and perform what you wanted

Comment: Because in my database I keep all the Chauffeur('s) driving one route

Comment: That doesn't even make sense you have to check whether or not i is greater than your Chauffeurlijst.count and it has nothing to do with you DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using another local variable to determine the index for Voertuigenlijst. Basically, you want to check that the index is within your range. If not, then use the last index in your list. For example --

```
for (int i = 0; i < Chauffeurlijst.Count; i++)
{
    var j = i < Voertuigenlijst.Count ? i : Voertuigenlijst.Count - 1;
    db.Insert("Insert into route (Voertuigen_ID,Chauffeurs_ID,Planning_ID) VALUES(@voertuigid,@chauffeurid,@planningid",
        new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@voertuigid", Voertuigenlijst[j].ID),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@chauffeurid", Chauffeurlijst[i].ID),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@planningid", planning.ID)
        });
}
```

This will use the last `Voertuig` in the list if `Chauffeurlijst.Count` > `Voertuigenlijst.Count`. However, this code does not handle the case where `Voertuigenlijst.Count` > `Chauffeurlijst.Count`. I'm sure you can figure out a good solution using this example though. You may also want to handle the case where one is empty.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the answer and thinking along with me. The answer is indeed exactly what I need. It is not possible for Voertuigenlijst.count > Chauffeurlijst.Count. And it's also not possible for one to be empty as both variables are checked way before this.

Comment: Great! No problem